# How can I use Mathematica to solve a Stefan Problem using an explicit scheme?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, physics, heat-equation

I would like to plot the temperature distribution for a particular case. the problem is stated in the paper, behind a paywall [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.4208/eajam.030513.200513a), summarized as

> Consider a one-dimensional container of length l, full of liquid with a freezing temperature $T_m$. Suppose the initial temperature of the liquid $T_L$ is higher than $T_m$, and one end of the liquid x = 0 is maintained at temperature $T_S$ (< $T_m$) for t > 0, whereas the other end $x = l$ is insulated. The solidification process consequently starts from $x = 0$, and extends over increasing intervals as the time $t$ increases (a well-known Stefan problem). We assume that the material density $\rho$ is constant; and the thermophysical properties are the latent heat $L$, the respective specific heats of the liquid and solid $c_L$ and $c_S$, and the respective thermal conductivities of the liquid and solid $k_L$ and $k_S$.

The initial and boundary conditions are given by,

[image]

The temperature distribution follows

[image]

where $E(x,t)$ is the enthalpy at time $t$ and position $x$. The enthalpy at time zero is 
$$E(x,0) = \rho c_L (T_L-T_m) + \rho L$$

and for later times is given by

[image]
Taking $T_L=37^\circ \mathrm{C}$, $T_S=-200^\circ \mathrm{C}$, and $l=0.1\mathrm{m}$, and the other constants defined below, how can I calculate the temperature distribution using *Mathematica*?

[image]

Where is the problem? If I'd like to have a temperature (T) distribution at t=1000s, then i need data at t=999s. Which makes it quite awkward to write code in *Mathematica*. Can anyone help me on this?

This is the work I have done so far:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
T[i_, n_] := 
 If[En[i, n] <= 0, 
  Tm + En[i, n]/(ρ cs), 
  If[0 < En[i, n] < ρ L, Tm, 
   If[ρ L <= E[i, n], 
    Tm + (En[i, n] - ρ L)/(ρ cl)]]]
En[i_, n_ + 1] := 
 En[i, n + 1] = 
  En[i, n] + Δt/Δx*(-ks (
       T[i, n] - T[i - 1, n])/Δx - 
      kl (T[i, n] - T[i + 1, n])/Δx)
T[0, n_] := T1[t] /. t -> n Δt;
M = 5;
T[M, n_] := T2[t] /. t -> n Δt;
T[i_, 0] := T0[x] /. x -> i Δx
En[i_, 0] := ρ cl (T1[0] - Tm) + ρ L;

L = 0.1; ks = 0.00266; kl = 0.006; \
cs = 1.7; cl = 4.1868; ρ = 1000;
Δt = 0.1; Δx = L/M; Tm = 0;

T0[x_] = -200;
T1[t_] = 37;
T2[t_] = -200;

Table[ListPlot[Table[{Δx i, T[i, n]}, {i, 0, M}], 
  PlotJoined -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 0.4}, AxesLabel -> {"x", ""}, 
  PlotLabel -> "T[x,t], t=" <> ToString[Δt n]], {n, 0, 
  80, 20}]
```

Would it be possible to model both types of phase transitions - not just freezing but also melting?

Comment: I need to know a little bit more.  So the material is length `L` - do you have it divided into subsections?  If so, how many?  What are E and rho?  Both E and T have two different forms - a continuous form, $E(x,t)$ and $T(x,t)$, and a form with sub and superscripts - $E^n_i$ and $T^n_i$.  How are they related?  You also have $T_m$.  Be more explicit, or provide a link to where the problem is laid out in more detail.

Comment: @JasonB I edited the question. Thanks in advanced for any feedback!

Comment: do you have some good reason not to use `NDSolve` ?

Comment: @george2079 Yes - method comparison. I did all this in excel, but the precision is limited. Doing this in Mathematica it's a little bit of a problem. But if you are thinking to use NDSolve for solving upper equations, then i don't know what you mean

Comment: ok, show the code you have so far so folks can see where you are stuck.  I'm not getting why 999 seconds is an issue at all??

Comment: @george2079 999 seconds it's not a problem, the way to 999 seconds is. I can't find a way to properly write a code that would instatly lead me to e.g. 999 seconds. By the equations above, i'd need 999 solved equations, in order to get temperature distribution at t=999s (998 + equation for t=0)

Comment: just march it out, `Nest[ <code to update E,T> ,  <initial E> , num time steps ]`.  (This is the point of an explicit scheme you don't need to solve simultaneously for all time at once )

Comment: @halirutan I added code and i hope the topic is remove from "put on hold" list

Comment: Related:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58622/1871

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a function that can return the temperature dynamics for a one-dimensional fluid for a given amount of time.  The entire fluid is initially held at temperature `T=Tinitial`, one end is insulated and stays at this temperature for all time. The other end is in contact with an infinite reservoir at temperature `T=Tsource`, which can be lower or higher than `Tinitial`.  The accuracy depends on the timestep, `Δt` and the number of gridpoints.

```
temperaturelist[Tinitial_, Tsource_, Δt_, tfinal_, ngridpoints_] := Module[{
    L = 333.73,
    ks = 0.00266,
    kl = 0.0006,
    cs = 1.7,
    cl = 4.1868,
    ρ = 1000,
    Tm = 0,
    tmax, ntpoints, ntdatapoints, Δx,
    temperature, tempfunction, templist,
    enthalpy, Δenthfunc
    },

   Δx = 0.1/ngridpoints;
   tmax = tfinal*60;
   ntpoints = Round[tmax/Δt];
   ntdatapoints = 300;

   (*Constants defined above, next define the temperature as an instantaneous local function of the enthalpy*)
   tempfunction[enth_] := Tm + Which[enth <= 0,
      enth/(ρ cs),
      0 < enth < ρ L,
      0,
      enth >= ρ L,
      (enth - ρ L)/(ρ cl)
      ];

   (*Next define the change in enthalpy, which depends on the instantaneous temperature for the grid point in question and
     also on the nearest neighbor grid points*)

   Δenthfunc[temp_] := Module[{klist, qminus, qplus},
     klist = If[# < Tm, ks, kl] & /@ temp; 
     qminus = -((temp - RotateRight[temp])/(.5 Δx (1/klist +1/RotateRight[klist])))[[2 ;; -2]];
     qplus = -((RotateLeft[temp] - temp)/(.5 Δx (1/klist +1/RotateLeft[klist])))[[2 ;; -2]];
     Δt/Δx (qminus - qplus)
     ];
   (* Define the initial temperature and enthalpy *)   
   temperature = ConstantArray[Tinitial, ngridpoints];
   temperature[[1]] = Tsource;
   enthalpy = 
    ConstantArray[
     If[Tinitial > Tm, ρ cl (Tinitial - Tm) + ρ L, ρ cs (Tinitial -Tm)], ngridpoints - 2];

   (* Next run the temperature dynamics simulation.  The value of Δt is critical here, or else the results are nonsense *)
   PrintTemporary[
    "Running dynamics, number of timepoints = " <> 
     IntegerString[ntpoints]];
   Monitor[
    templist = Reap[
        Do[
         temperature[[2 ;; -2]] = tempfunction /@ enthalpy;
         enthalpy += Δenthfunc[temperature];
         If[Mod[n - 1, Round[ntpoints/ntdatapoints]] == 0, 
          Sow[temperature]];
         , {n, ntpoints + 1}]][[2, 1]];
    , n];
   (* Return the result *)
   templist
   ];
```

Here are two examples, one for freezing, the other for melting:

```
tlist1 = temperaturelist[37., -200., 0.1, 50, 128];
tlist2 = temperaturelist[-37., 200., 0.1, 50, 128];
```

and here are plots of the results, with the red line marking the boundary between liquid and solid phases.

```
Grid[{(Show[
      ListDensityPlot[#, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
       DataRange -> {{0, .1}, {0, 50}}, 
       FrameLabel -> {"x (m)", "t (min)"}, ImageSize -> 400],
      ListContourPlot[#, ContourShading -> None, Contours -> {0}, 
       DataRange -> {{0, .1}, {0, 50}}, ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Red}}]
      ] & /@ {tlist1, tlist2})}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great work! Many thanks! This is very useful and other approach to the problem. The ListDensityPlot is not working properly, due to one ']' too many, but I'll figure it out eventually. Thank you!

Comment: Corrected . `Show[` was added

Comment: Do you perhaps know why it doesn't work for the opposite case when defining initial conditions, e.g.   `Tl = 10+ 273.15;
    Ts = -10 + 273.15;` and initial temperature is `-10+273` - Where is that defined in your code?

Comment: I don't see what your question is.  If you make the changes you say, then the answer comes out correct.  The initial temperature is `Tl`

Comment: The initial temperature is `Ts` and condition `T(x=0,t) = 10` must be applied. I understand physics and what is the end result of this, i just have a few problems understanding the code in order to properly modify the section of code with initial condtions.

Comment: If you look at the equations from the paper, one end of the liquid, at `x=0`, is held for all times at `T=Ts` (so in this example, you have `T(x=0,t) = -10` because we set `Ts=-10` degrees C.  The other end, at `x=l` is kept for all times at `T=Tl`.  In this code, the initial conditions are set right after I say above "We define the initial temperatures and enthalpies,"

Comment: I know, this works great for this example. For the mentioned case above i changed `temperature = ConstantArray[Ts, M];` in order to get `T(x,t=0) = -10` and `temperature[[1]] = Tl;` in order to get `T(x=0,t)=10`- But it doesn't work as i hoped it would. This is why i'm looking at the entire code.

Comment: Sorry if I caused any inconveniances. I'm just trying to work this out, with not very much Mathematica background.

Comment: Now you are changing the problem after the fact - you want to not only be able to model freezing of a liquid but also melting of a solid.  This physical model can do both, but the code I wrote only does freezing.  I've just changed it to be more versatile, so I will post that here shortly.

Comment: But I think that you need more experience with programming, before tackling such a problem.  It doesn't need to be Mathematica, this would be a fun exercise in C++ or python.  Become more familiar with lists, with loops, etc.  Also, the equations you posted originally were wrong - specifically the enthalpy equations.  When you combined them from the original paper, you made some errors that would have doomed you even if your programming were perfect - so I had to go to the source paper and figure it out myself.