# Using NDSolve to solve heat equation using simple initial and boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to familiarize myself with using *Mathematica*'s `NDSolve` to solve PDEs. I'm using a simple one-dimensional heat equation as a start.
The initial condition is a sine function and I'm expecting a standing wave as a solution of the heat equation. For some reason, plotting the result gives an empty plot.

What's the problem here? Is the code causing the solution to be zero everywhere (for all values of `x`) for all values of `t`?

```
ss == NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t, t] == D[u[x, t], x, x], 
    u[x, 0] == Sin[x], u[0, t] == 0, u[Pi, t] == 0}, 
   u, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 3}];

list = Table[Plot[ss[x, t], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1.3}], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}];

ListAnimate[list]
```

Comment: The first thing I see is that you have `ss == NDSolve`, but it should be `ss = NDSolve`

Comment: totally unrelated, but also a heat equation solution using *Mathematica*: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95358/9490

Answer (score 4):

First, you should use `Set` (`=`) not `Equal` (`==`) for `ss = NDSolve....`. Second, `NDSolve` gives a nested list of rules (with `->`), so you need to extract the actual interpolating function with `First` and `ReplaceAll` (`/.`):

```
ss = u /. 
  First @ NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t, t] == D[u[x, t], x, x], 
     u[x, 0] == Sin[x], u[0, t] == 0, u[Pi, t] == 0}, 
    u, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 3}]

list = Table[Plot[ss[x, t], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1.3}], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}];

ListAnimate[list]
```

[image]