# Moving B.C.s in heat diffusion model

Tags: differential-equations, programming, matlab, heat-equation

I came across the paper *Solidification dynamics of an impacted drop regarding a heat equations* by Thiévenaz et.al and was interested in knowing how they obtained the graphs presented. From what I understand, they solved the PDE presented below, with a moving boundary using the finite differences method. I did solve them in matlab but was wondering how one would do this in mathematica given that the flexibility of matlab with matrices is much greater. The code in matlab may be found [*here*](https://we.tl/t-44yTjPHpWd).
The relevant equations are:
The two heat equations for the temperature field $T(z,t)$
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=D_s\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}, \,\,z\leq0;\qquad \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=D_i\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}, \,\,0\leq z\leq h(t)$$
and the four boundary conditions:

$$T(0^-,t)=T(0^+,t);\quad \lambda_s\frac{\partial T(0^-,t)}{\partial t}=\lambda_i\frac{\partial T(0^+,t)}{\partial t};\quad T(h(t)^-,t)=T_m;$$
$$\lambda_i\frac{\partial T(h(t)^-,t)}{\partial t}=\rho_i L\frac{dh}{dt}$$
where $L$ denotes the latent heat of solidification, $\rho_k$ the thermal density, $\lambda_n$ the thermal conductivity, $D_k=\lambda_k/(\rho_kC_k)$ the diffusion coefficient. Here $k$ denotes $l$ in the liquid phase, $i$ in the solid phase and $s$ for the substrate (they are all constant parameters).
It is also imposed a constant temperature $T_s$ deep in the substrate, i.e.,
$$\lim_{z\to-\infty}T(z,t)=T_s,\quad T(z,0)=T_s\quad z\leq0, h(0)=0$$
which means that at time $0$ the liquid is put into contact with the substrate.

A pictorial description of the model is showed below:
[image]

Note: The constants mentioned above in my code are chosen arbitrarily (i.e. I chose the values assigned to them)

I did not post the code because it was somewhat long.

---

As requested in the comments, the scheme I used was:

$$\vec{T^{\,n+1}}=A^{-1}\left(\vec{T^{\,n}}+\vec{B}\right)\implies c\rho\frac{T_i^{n+1}-T_i^n}{\Delta t}=k\frac{T_{i-1}^{n+1}-2T_i^{n+1}+T_{i+1}^n}{\Delta x^2}$$
which is the implicit version. The explicit is similar, and looks like
$$c\rho\frac{T_i^{n+1}-T_i^n}{\Delta t}=k\frac{T_{i-1}^{n}-2T_i^{n}+T_{i+1}^n}{\Delta x^2}$$
In my code you will see how I found $A$ and $B$. ($A$ is a matrix and $B$ a vector)

Comment: I'd say Mathematica and MATLAB are about the same when it comes to 95% of the major matrix ops, but maybe you mean element-wise manipulation? Also I think it'd be nice to at least post _some_ code detailing the method used. It's a big ask for us to read, translate, and do all the mental processing without any sort of starting point.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes what I meant was element-wise manipulation. And it appears to me it feels more natural in matlab when doing so, or maybe I’m not experienced enough in mathematica. Regarding the method, as I mentioned above, I used the finite difference method which there are a lot of snippets around the web. I will try to post some code, maybe the general idea. Anyways, any help is appreciated. It’s just a curiosity

Comment: I'd say most element-wise tasks can be done better as vectorized operations and once you do that there's really no difference between Mathematica and MATLAB. That's really neither here nor there, though. Looks like you just need to use the FDM, from what I glanced at in that image. Lots of questions here pertain to that but maybe xczd will come by and help you. Also how about as a compromise for not having some preliminary code, you post the relevant equations here in LaTeX form?

Comment: @b3m2a1 will do. Thank you

Comment: @b3m2a1 I've seen this post the moment it's posted, and have been fighting against the urge to vote to close since then. As mentioned by b3m2a1, this is a big ask, which is out of scope of this site in many cases. (There exist subtle cases of course. ) Also, it's a bad idea to provide code using external download link, because the link may be easily dead. (This aleady happened for several times in this site. )

Comment: Finally, we already have a few posts about moving b.c., have you read them?: 1. 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58596/1871 2. 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130962/1871 3. 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95358/1871 4. 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114967/1871 5. 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184920/1871

Comment: @xzczd Unfortuntely, I had no other way of providing the code. Although I understand that a broken link may be an issue since such code would not be retrievable anymore. Do you think I should post it? I began translating the code myself, however being that I am somewhat inexperienced in Mathematica, I preferred posing the question to other people here, also because I did not get very far (and used many while and for loops which apparently are bad practice in Mathematica). If the question does not conform to the standards of the site, feel free to close it.  I will look at the links u suggested

Comment: The question is much better after the edits. (Still, you need to show us the parameters and i.c.s. ) I'd say the MATLAB code isn't quite related to this question in my view. Is the finite difference scheme used by the paper necessary? If so, it'll be better to add the difference scheme to the question directly, because it's easier for us to understand the difference formula in traditional math notation. If not, then I believe the combination of `DChange`, `pdetoode` and `NDSolve` is a better choice for solving the problem, and again, we don't need to know how the MATLAB code looks like.

Comment: @xzczd My goal here was to convert my matlab code (which works) to the mathematica one, mostly for comparison, so that is why I insisted on the difference scheme. The parameters, as I mentioned in the post, are picked arbitrarily. I will add the scheme as soon as I get back from work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @xzczd I included the scheme I followed

Comment: Well, how is the moving boundary handled by this scheme?

Comment: that's what I am having trouble with dong in mathematica

Comment: ……Then how did you handle it in MATLAB?

Comment: @xzczd I simply created two functions for which when $x<s$ it returned a $\rho_1c_1$, if $x>s$ it returned $\rho_2c_2$ other wise it returned the average. I then did something similar to handle the other constants. Then I called these two functions in my iterative scheme that I presented. Although I am not sure how to do this in mathematica as I do no really know how to work with the implementations of matrices (for example a dynamic allocation of data on it), which is needed when implementing the iterative scheme. I also looked at the links you provided but none handle the case with $x<0$

Comment: So, there's no moving boundary  $h(t)$ in your MATLAB code? "I also looked at the links you provided but none handle the case with $x<0$" The $x=0$ boundary isn't moving, it's much easier to handle compared to the moving boundary, we also have several posts about the topic, for example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121739/1871

Comment: Well, what answer are you expecting? I've also checked your MATLAB code, the moving b.c. isn't considered therein, if I've understand it correctly. Translating the MATLAB code into _Mathematica_ code won't help.

Comment: @xzczd I thought I implemented it correctly. Then, I am looking for a solution of the problem I presented above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, OP's MATLAB implementation doesn't seem to be correct, so I'll just give a solution to OP's problem.

Since the heat flux continuity involves in, there's indeed something new in this problem compared to [previous ones](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/moving-b-c-s-in-heat-diffusion-model#comment541005_211080). We first handle the continuity condition. Notice that, strictly speaking, 1D heat conduction equation is **not**

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\frac{\lambda}{\rho C}\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}$$

but

$${\rho C}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\lambda\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}\right)$$

These 2 equations are equivalent only if $\lambda$ is constant, and piecewise constant is not constant. "So what? Why you mention this? " Because the latter equation owns a good property: when it's discretized directly, the heat continuity condition will be automatically satisfied.

Then we need to deal with the moving b.c.. As usual, we use the "change the variable -> discretize" method, with the help of [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871).

Given that OP hasn't shown the parameters, they'll be casually chosen as

```
ρL = 1; eps = 10^-2;
inf = 2; Tm = 1; Ts = 2; tend = 10;
ρc = Piecewise[{{2, z > 0}}, 1];
λ = Piecewise[{{3, z > 0}}, 1];
icexpr = Piecewise[{{Ts, z > 0}}, Tm];
```

Next we interpret the PDE, i.c. and b.c. to *Mathematica* code:

```
With[{T = T[z, t], dT = dT[z, t]}, 
 eq = ρc D[T, t] == D[dT, z];
 eqd = dT == λ D[T, z];
 bc = {{λ D[T, z] == ρL h'[t], T == Ts} /. z -> h[t], 
       T == Tm /. z -> -inf};
 icextra = h[0] == eps;
 ic = T == icexpr /. t -> 0;]
```

Then we change the variable with [`DChange`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871):

```
unitStepExpand = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@# &;
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
{neweqd, neweq, newicmid, newbcmid} = 
  DChange[{eqd, eq, ic, bc}, ζ == scale z, z, ζ, {T[z, t], dT[z, t]}] /. 
    a_Piecewise :> unitStepExpand@a /. 
   scale -> unitStepExpand@Piecewise[{{1/h[t], ζ > 0}}, 1];

newic = newicmid /. t -> 0 /. Rule @@ icextra

newbc = {newbcmid[[1]] /. ζ -> 1, newbcmid[[2]] /. ζ -> -inf}
```

Discretize the system:

```
domain@1 = {-inf, 0};
domain@2 = {0, 1};
points = 400;
difforder = 2;
gridfunc = Array[# &, points, #] &;
grid = gridfunc@domain@1~Join~Rest@gridfunc@domain@2;

(*Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
  please find it in the link above.*)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{T, dT}[ζ, t], t, grid, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
With[{eq = neweq, eqd = neweqd, ic = newic, bc = newbc},
 ode = Block[{dT}, Set @@ ptoofunc /@ eqd;
                   del@ptoofunc@eq];
 odeic = ptoofunc@ic;
 odebc = ptoofunc@bc;]
```

The resulting system is a DAE system and `NDSolve` can't handle it well, so we create a `toode` function to transform the system to an ODE system (For more info check [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871) post) and solve:

```
toode = With[{sf = 10}, diffbc[t, sf]];
{funch, funcTlist} = 
  NDSolveValue[
   MapAt[toode, {ode, icextra, odeic, odebc} /. T[i_] :> T@ToString@i // 
     Flatten, {{-1}, {-2}}], {h, T@ToString@# & /@ grid}, {t, 0, tend}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity];

funcT[1] = rebuild[funcTlist[[;; points]], grid[[;; points]], 2];
funcT[2] = rebuild[funcTlist[[-points ;;]], grid[[-points ;;]], 2];
func = Function[{z, t}, 
   Piecewise[{{funcT[1][z, t], z <= 0}, {Ts, z >= funch[t]}}, 
    funcT[2][z/funch[t], t]]];
```

Finally, just some illustration:

```
ListLinePlot[funch, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Here `funch` is plotted using an [undocumented syntax](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134223/1871).

```
Manipulate[Plot[func[z, t], {z, -inf, funch[tend]}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "T"}], {t, 0, tend}]
```

[image]

```
Animate[DensityPlot[func[z, t], {x, 0, 1}, {z, -inf, funch[tend]}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"], {t, 
  0., tend, 0.05}]
```

[image]

Comment: The process is very clear. I will have to look up the definitions to understand the code. Anyways, thank you for putting the time

Comment: @DMH16 I just noticed the moving grid method is wrong. See the corrected answer. (The difference is not obvious in this case, but it does exist. )