# solve pde with moving top boundary

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve this pde (1D diffusion with source term) with a top boundary that moves over time noted as L0[t]. The NDsolve works when L0=constant, but here the top boundary changes in height with time.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{d, c, solN, pars, L0, pde, ic, bc, x, u, t, B, phi, phistart,
    k, mu, H}, {B = 10^-5, phistart = 0.2, mu = 3.6*10^-5, H = 3.5};
  phi[t] = phistart - c*t;
  L0[t] = H - ((H*c*t)/(1 - phistart));
  k[t] = (((phi[t])^3)*d^2)/(150*(1 - phi[t])^2);
  pde = D[u[x, t], t] == 
    k[t]/(B*phi[t]*mu)*
      D[(1 + B*u[x, t])*D[u[x, t], x], 
       x] - ((1 + B*u[x, t])/((B*phi[t]*(1 - phi[t]))))*
      D[phi[t], t] + NeumannValue[0, x == 0];
  bc = u[L0[t], t] == 0;
  ic = u[x, 0] == (L0[t] - x)/L0;(*made up IC*)
  pars = {d -> d0, c -> c0};
  solN = NDSolve[Evaluate[{pde, ic, bc} /. pars], 
    u, {x, 0, L0[t]}, {t, 0, t0}];
  Quiet@Plot[Evaluate[u[0, t] /. solN], {t, 0, t0}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "u(0,t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12]], {{d0, 0.0001, 
   "Particle diameter [m]"}, 0.0001, 0.1, 0.0001, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c0, 0, "porosity rate of change c"}, 0, 
  0.0001, 10^-6, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t0, 1, "time (s)"}, 0.1, 
  maxTime, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{maxTime, 3000}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, t0}]
```

What would need changing to make this work?

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/211080/1871 Don't miss the links there.

Comment: A NeumannValue is a spatial boundary condition not a temporal one; besides Neumann 0 is ignored anyways, you can remove that.