# How to solve a system of PDEs with zip condition?

Tags: differential-equations, heat-equation

I have a system of PDEs in the following form,

$$\frac{\partial T_1}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 T_1}{\partial x^2},\,\,0<x<S(t)$$
with $T_1(x,0)=-10,\,\,T_1(0,t)=-10,\,\, T_1(S(t),t)=10$, and
$$\frac{\partial T_2}{\partial t}+\frac{dS(t)}{dt}\frac{\partial T_2}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial^2 T_2}{\partial x^2},\,\,x>S(t)$$
with $T_2(x,0)=10,\,\,T_2(S(t),t)=10,\,\, T_2(20,t)=20$.

The above two equations are zip together by 
$$\frac{dS(t)}{dt}=\frac{\partial T_1}{\partial x}\Biggl|_{x=S(t)}-\frac{\partial T_2}{\partial x}\Biggl|_{x=S(t)}$$
with $S(0)=0$.

```
Eq1 = D[T1[x, t], t] == D[T1[x, t], x, x]
Eq2 = D[T2[x, t], t]+D[S[t], t] D[T2[x, t], x]== D[T2[x, t], x, x]
T1[x, 0] == -10,T1[0,t] == -10, T1[S(t), t] == 10,T2[x, 0] == 10,T2[S(t), t] == 10,T2[20, t] == 20
```

Is there a way to solve the above system in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This problem is quite similar to [PDE with Stefan Conditions, a.k.a variable boundary](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58596/1871), and can be solved more easily because now we have [`DChange`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871) and [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871).

We first use `DChange` to transform $T_1(x_1,t)$ and $T_2(x_2,t)$ to $T_1(\xi,t)$ and $T_2(\xi,t)$, where

$$\frac{x_1}{S(t)}=\xi$$
$$\frac{x_2-S(t)}{20-S(t)}=\xi$$

```
xR = 20;
eqL = D[T1[x, t], t] == D[T1[x, t], x, x];
eqR = D[T2[x, t], t] + D[S[t], t] D[T2[x, t], x] == D[T2[x, t], x, x];
{icL, icR} = {T1[x, 0] == -10, T2[x, 0] == 10};
{bcL, bcR} = {{T1[0, t] == -10, T1[S@(t), t] == 10}, 
              {T2[S@(t), t] == 10, T2[xR, t] == 20}};
slopeL = (D[T1[x, t], x] /. x -> S[t]);
slopeR = (D[T2[x, t], x] /. x -> S[t]);
bcmidfunc = S'[t] == # - #2 &;
With[{eps = 10^-10}, icmid = S[0] == eps];
(* Definition of DChange isn't included in this code piece,
   please find it in the link above *)
changeL = DChange[#, x/S@t == ξ, x, ξ, T1[x, t]] &;
changeR = DChange[#, (x - S[t])/(xR - S[t]) == ξ, x, ξ, T2[x, t]] &;

(* Definition of diffbc isn't included in this code piece,
   please find it in the link above *)
toode = With[{sf = 100}, diffbc[t, sf]];

{neweqL, newicL, newbcL, newslopeL} = 
 changeL@{eqL, icL, toode@bcL, slopeL} /. S[0] -> S[t]
{neweqR, newicR, newbcR, newslopeR} = 
 changeR@{eqR, icR, toode@bcR, slopeR} /. S[0] -> S[t] // Simplify
```

> **Remark**
>
> 1. The `/. S[0] -> S[t]` is added because currently `DChange` can't
>    handle coefficients involving the independent variable very well.
> 2. Check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871) if you
>    don't understand why we need `toode`.

After the change of variable, $T_1$ and $T_2$ are both defined in $[0,1]\times[0,t_{end}]$, while $S$ is defined in $[0,t_{end}]$, so `NDSolve` still can't solve the equation set directly. We need to discretize the PDEs to a set of ODEs. I'll use `pdetoode` for the task:

```
points = 25;
xdifforder = 4;
{ξL, ξR} = domain = {0, 1};
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];

(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this code piece,
   please find it in the link above *)
ptoo = pdetoode[{T1, T2}[ξ, t], t, grid, xdifforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

{odeL, odeicL, odebcL, odeslopeL, odeR, odeicR, odebcR, odeslopeR} = 
    MapAt[del, ptoo /@ {neweqL, newicL, newbcL, newslopeL, neweqR, newicR, newbcR, 
          newslopeR}, {{1}, {5}}];
   
odebcmid = bcmidfunc[odeslopeL, odeslopeR]
odeicmid = icmid;
tend = 40;
sollst = NDSolveValue[{odeL, odeR, odeicL, odeicR, odebcL, odebcR, 
        odebcmid, odeicmid}, {T1 /@ grid, T2 /@ grid, S}, {t, 0, tend}];

solL = rebuild[#, grid, -1]&@sollst[[1]];
solR = rebuild[#, grid, -1]&@sollst[[2]];
solS = sollst[[-1]];
sol = {x, t} \[Function] 
      Piecewise[{{solL[x/solS@t, t], ξL <= x/solS@t <= ξR}}, 
        solR[(x - solS[t])/(xR - solS[t]), t]];

Manipulate[Plot[sol[x, t], {x, 0, xR}, PlotRange -> {-10, 20}], {t, 0, tend}]
(* Plot3D[sol[x, t], {x, 0, xR}, {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> {-10, 20}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50] *)
```

[image]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I am unable to run your code without error.

Comment: @mmm Have you already execute the definition of `DChange` and `pdetoode`?

Comment: Now it is working. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to plot `S` vs `t`?

Comment: @mmm Sure, just run `Plot[solS[t], {t, 0, tend}]`