# Solving Stefan's solidification problem - moving boundary issue

Tags: differential-equations

I have used the (amazing) work done by @xzczd

In this question:
[How to solve a system of PDEs with zip condition?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130962/how-to-solve-a-system-of-pdes-with-zip-condition)

in order to solve a similar problem.
I ran into a problem to define S(0)=0 (same as in the attacked question).
when i plot S(t) Vs time i see that in both my case and the example mentioned S(0) starts at x=1. 
Is there a way to change it to S(0)=0?
Thanks,
Ofek.

Comment: Oh that's because I forgot to add the $S(0)=0$ to the discretized system so `NDSolve` has automatically chosen $S(0)=1$. Now the code has been revised. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and effort, the codes you wrote made so much help for me.