# Solving partial differential equation with a moving boundary

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a time dependent diffusion equation of a shrinking particle sphere with radius r (at time=0, let it be r[0]).The particle has a solute concentration of 100%, and the matrix solute concentration in equilibrium is C0=Exp[-Subscript[E, v]/k/T], reached infinitely far from the particle. The solute concentration at the particle surface is Cr=Exp[2*[CapitalOmega]*[Gamma]/r/k/T]*C0 because of the capillary effect.

**The essence of the problem is the boundary r is dynamically changed due to diffusion.**

Use the Fick's second law:

```
D[c[x, t], t] - Subscript[D, 0]*Exp[-(Subscript[E, m])/k/T]/\[CapitalOmega]/\[Xi]* D[D[c[x, t], x], x] == 0
```

With the Boundary condition:

```
c[x, 0] == Exp[-Subscript[E, v]/k/T] + r[0]/x*Exp[-Subscript[E, v]/k/T] (Exp[2*\[CapitalOmega]*\[Gamma]/r[0]/k/T] - 1)
c[Infinity, t] == Exp[-Subscript[E, v]/k/T]
```

We can list the PDE

```
pde = D[c[x, t], t] - 
   Subscript[D, 0]*Exp[-(Subscript[E, m])/k/T]/\[CapitalOmega]/\[Xi]* 
    D[D[c[x, t], x], x] == 0
sol = DSolve[{pde, 
   c[x, 0] == 
     Exp[-Subscript[E, v]/k/T] + 
      r[0]/x*Exp[-Subscript[E, v]/k/
         T] (Exp[2*\[CapitalOmega]*\[Gamma]/r[0]/k/T] - 1),
   c[Infinity, t] == Exp[-Subscript[E, v]/k/T], c[r, t] == Exp[-Subscript[E, v]/k/T]*Exp[2*\[CapitalOmega]*\[Gamma]/r/k/T]}, c[x, t], {x, t}]
```

The symbols beside radius, time and concentrations are just parameters with real values, If you want.

```
T = 373;
\[Gamma] = 6.24; \[CapitalOmega] = 0.0166; 
r[0] = 10; k = 8.6173324*10^\[Minus]5; Subscript[E, m] = 0.65;
Subscript[E, v] = 0.65;
Subscript[D, 0] = 1; \[Xi] = 0.781;
```

However, it did not work. There is a solution if I drop the c[Infinity, t] and c[r,t] boundary, but the solution contains an extra unknown function K[1]. Where went wrong...I need some helps.

Best regards,

Jack

Comment: Obtain the `DSolve` solution without initial and boundary conditions, if you can, and then apply the boundary conditions to determine the unknown function.  By the way, using `Subscript` variables in a problem like this is asking for difficulty.

Comment: And, AFAIK, `DSolve` can't handle b.c. at infinity directly (at least now).

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58596/18437)?